# Can I manipulate an image in the browser with github pages?

Tags: python, github-pages

Is it possible to upload and manipulate a photo in the browser with GitHub-pages? The photo doesn't need to be stored else than just for that session.

PS. I'm new to this area and I am using python to manipulate the photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub pages allows users to create static HTML sites. This means you have no control over the server which hosts the HTML files - it is essentially a file server.

Even if you did have full control over the server (e.g. if you hosted your own website), it would *not* be possible to allow the client to run Python code in the browser since the browser only interprets JavaScript.

Therefore the most easy solution is to re-write your code in JavaScript.

Failing this, you could offer a download link to your Python script, and have users trust you enough to run it on their computer.